# Asign an object to a specific ID with geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm trying to create a city block with geometry nodes.

I've managed to successfully create a block with randomised instances of city blocks with a length I can set in the group input.

I'm trying to replace the ends of my block with specific 'corner' buildings. I've found a way to isolate the IDs of the vertices at eather end of my row of buildings (One is ID zero - the other is set through the length in the group input) But I'd like to know how to place either specific objects or instances from a **different** collection to the other blocks in the row.

Is there a way I can tell a specific vertix ID to refer to a different object/collection to other buildings in the row. (Row is defined by a grid)

Here's my blend file (its probably a mess): https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/nkkry7pc69ziokmss0mgj/citybuildingnodesbrokenmess.blend?rlkey=olwln6ywyacphkkfpi2nfgj43&dl=0